# XLST convert XML to CSV

Tags: xml, csv

I have the below .XML that I am trying to convert to CSV. The issues I am having is the repeating "Batch job" tag keeps appearing in the output, when all I need is a list of the batch content. So the output I am trying to get to is:

GX2320,GX2023,GX2218  Etc.

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
 <batch job="1">
    <index id="batch">GX2320</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="2">
    <index id="batch">GX2023</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="3">
    <index id="batch">GX2218</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="4">
    <index id="batch">GX2635</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="5">
    <index id="batch">GX2532</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="6">
    <index id="batch">MR12358</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="7">
    <index id="batch">GM1387</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="8">
    <index id="batch">GM1769</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="9">
    <index id="batch">GN6605</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="10">
    <index id="batch">GW1435</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="11">
    <index id="batch">GX2120</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="12">
    <index id="batch">GX2054</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="13">
    <index id="batch">GR42348</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="14">
    <index id="batch">GE26813</index>
  </batch>
  <batch job="15">
    <index id="batch">GR36258</index>
  </batch>
```

So far have been trying to get the below operational, but only getting blank file output as though it cant find each child statement:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/*/*/child::*">
   <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have been attempting to read each child statement and then pass forwards output is blank each time:  See above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going too deep in your template match. The context of `match="/*/*/child::*"` is going to be `index`. That element doesn't have any children elements so your `xsl:for-each` never selects anything.

Lets say it did select `index`. Then your `position()` test will never work because `index` is always at the first position.

You should match `batch` and output the value of `index`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*/batch">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(index)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: You can replace the `batch` and `index` names with `*` if needed.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes that works great, thank you for your input!